# What is the minimum-curvature curve interpolating a given set of points in the plane?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, terminology

We are given a set $X$ of $n\ge 3$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, belonging to the boundary of the convex hull of $X$ itself. Let $\Gamma(X)$ be the set of all *convex, simple closed* curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ passing through all points in $X$ such that, at any point $\mathbf{p}\in\gamma$, there exists a normal vector $\mathbf{n}_{\mathbf{p}}$ and a tangent vector $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbf{p}}$ lying on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\kappa_{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{p})$ the curvature of $\gamma$ at $\mathbf{p}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbf{p}}$.

I am looking for the name of the curve(s) $\gamma\in\Gamma(X)$ that ***minimizes*** the ***maximum*** curvature absolute value $|\kappa_{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{p})|$ *over all* points $\mathbf{p}\in\gamma$. I view it as a natural mathematical concept; therefore, I expect it is already mentioned in the related literature (although I could not find any reference yet).

*Besides the name (if it exists), I would be glad to have any reference about this topic.*

---

---

***Edit: After the discussion with SaúlRM and its answer, I added the constraint that $\gamma$ is convex.***

***Edit: After the comment of Yaakov Baruch, I added the constraint that all points of $X$ belong to the boundary of the convex hull of $X$ itself.***

Comment: I think it would be useful to give some extra conditions, e.g. the curves being contained in $S$. For example given a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it seems there are curves with arbitrarily low curvature passing through all the points

Comment: What does "pairwise non-collinear" mean?  Every pair of points is contained in a line.

Comment: @MattF. as I just wrote in the comment for SaúlRM, informally speaking, the idea is very simple: I want to measure *how curve must necessarily be* (i.e., I am interested in the *maximum* curvature over *all* points of the curve itself) a curve passing through a given sets of points $X$ on a plane $P$, when $X$ belong to a convex polygon.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati The problem is that, as I said above, there are simple closed curves of arbitrarily low curvature passing through any given finite set of points of ℝ2. So there is no curve minimizing the maximum curvature. I can draw in an answer what such a curve would look like if you want.

Comment: @SaúlRM  The curvature can be "arbitrarily low" in some specific points, but how can the *maximum curvature at point $\mathbf{p}$* *over all points* $\mathbf{p}\in\gamma$ be "arbitrarily low" ?

Comment: I think an optimal curve will be a union of line segments and circle arcs; if so, it should be easy to compute.

Comment: @MattF. do you think that if each triplet of points in $X$ consists of non-collinear points, then the optimal curve would be just the union of circle arcs solely?

Comment: Is there a simple proof that the optimal  curve through three points is a circle? It seems like it should be true but I don’t see a quick argument. I suppose that if the triangle is obtuse one can finding many minimizing curves, but it seems like there must be a circular arc through the vertices.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati Do you need the curvature to be defined everywhere? Or could it not be defined in a finite set of points? (e.g. the points of $X$)

Comment: To be clear: the points of $X$ are assumed to be all  on the boundary of the convex hull of $X$?

Comment: @SaúlRM the curvature is not restricted to belong to a finite portion of the space. Anyway, I think that this does not change the problem.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, initially I formulated the problem with the assumption you mentioned above in your last comment. I am adding it back to the problem text.

Comment: @MattF. I'm pretty sure that for the points $(0,\pm 1), (\pm a,0)$ for $a>1$ the optimal curve is a pill shape: 2 semicircles or radius $1$ joined by segments of length $2a-2$ (so definitely not an ellipse). If your guess is right in general, the details of the the arcs are going to be determined globally, not locally, so may not be so easy to compute.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati the thing is, I think the curve with minimal curvature, if it exists, is given by a sequence of arcs of circumference joining the points of $X$. However in the points of $X$, where the arcs of circumference meet, the curvature may not be defined, because the different arcs may have difference curvature. But if that's not a problem I'll try to write it in detail later

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, the ease of computing has two things going for it: 1) The optimal union of lines and circle-arcs, which may be optimal overall, can be computed exactly via Tarski-Seidenberg or the like. As a corollary, if the original points are algebraic, the optimal curvature will also be algebraic. 2) The algorithm in my answer gives a starting point, from which one can (repeatedly)  identify the arc with maximal curvature and evaluate possible replacements for it.

Comment: @SaúlRM I think it is fine, even if I am pretty sure there should be a method to transform such optimal curve in such a way that in the neighborhood of each point in $x\in X$ the curvature is defined and belongs to $(\kappa',\kappa'')$, where $\kappa'$ and $\kappa''$ are the curvatures of the two arcs connected at point $x$

Comment: @GabeK, if you are asking: “Is there a simple proof that the optimal curvature for three points can always be achieved by a circle?”, then Saul RM’s new answer shows that the optimal curvature can be achieved by at most three circle-arcs and three line segments; from there showing that it can be achieved by a single circle should be straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matt F. says, his answer is not optimal, but the optimal solution, for most polygons (see (!!) below) comes from a similar construction using just arcs of circumference and segments. This answer gives a finite dimensional family of curves containing the optimal curve, thus reducing the problem to minimizing some functions (with explicit expressions) from $[0,1]^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

We will begin by studying which "convex" curves under certain boundary conditions (the initial/final positions and speeds) minimize curvature.

Fix $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ with $a,b\geq0$ and some unit vector $v=(v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb{S}^1$ with $v_2>0$, and let $\Gamma$ be the set of $C^1$ curves $\gamma:[0,T_\gamma]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized by arc length such that:

- $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$, $\gamma'(0)=v$, $\gamma(T_\gamma)=(a,b)$ and $\gamma'(T_\gamma)=(1,0)$.
- Let $\alpha_{\gamma}(t)$ be the angle that $\gamma'(t)$ forms with the positive $x$-axis. Then $\alpha_\gamma(t)\in[0,\pi]\forall t$ and $\alpha_\gamma(t)$ is decreasing.

An example of such a curve is given by $c:[0,T_c]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ formed by a circumference arc and a horizontal segment, as in the figure below. Such a curve $c$ is unique in $\Gamma$, and exists if $\alpha(0)\geq\arccos(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$ (we will assume that is the case).

[image]

**Claim:** $c$ is the only curve of $\Gamma$ with least maximal curvature.

(If curvature is not defined everywhere, we can just interpret maximum curvature of $\gamma$ as the minimum Lipschitz constant of the map $t\mapsto\gamma'(t)$)

$\textit{Proof of the claim:}$ We will suppose that $\gamma\in\Gamma$ has less maximum curvature than $c$ and prove that $\gamma=c$. Both $\alpha_\gamma(t)$ and $\alpha_c(t)$ are decreasing, and the maximum curvature of $\gamma$ being less than that of $c$ implies that $\alpha_c(t)\leq\alpha_\gamma(t)\forall t$. Note that $\gamma(t)=\left(\int_0^t\cos(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt,
\int_0^t\sin(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt\right)$ for any $\gamma\in\Gamma$.

So as $\cos(\alpha_\gamma(t))\leq\cos(\alpha_c(t))\forall t$ and $a=\int_0^{T_\gamma}\cos(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt=\int_0^{T_c}\cos(\alpha_c(t))dt$, we have $T_\gamma\geq T_c$. Now first suppose that $\alpha_c(0)<\frac{\pi}{2}$, so that $\sin(\alpha_c)(t),\sin(\alpha_\gamma)(t)>0$ for all $t$.

Then $b=\int_0^{T_c}\sin(\alpha_c(t))dt\leq\int_0^{T_c}\sin(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt 
\leq\int_0^{T_\gamma}\sin(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt=b$. So all the inequalities are equalities, meaning that $\alpha(t)=\beta(t)\forall t$, that is, $c$ and $\gamma$ are the same curve.

If $\alpha(0)>\frac{\pi}{2}$, the proof I found is more complicated, here is a sketch. let $t_\gamma=\inf\{t;\alpha_\gamma(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}\},t_c=(\alpha_c)^{-1}(\frac{\pi}{2})$. Then we can prove that $\gamma(t_\gamma)-c(t_c)$ has negative $x$-coordinate and, as above, deduce that $T_c-t_c\leq T_\gamma-t_\gamma$, so, letting $y(p)$ be the second coordinate of $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we get $b-y(c(t_c))\leq\int_{t_c}^{T_c}\sin(\alpha_c(t))dt\leq\int_{t_\gamma}^{T_\gamma}\sin(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt=b-y(\gamma(t_\gamma))$, with equality iff $T_c-t_c=T_\gamma-t_\gamma$ $\alpha_\gamma(t_\gamma+t)=\alpha_c(t_c+t)$ for all $t>0$.

We also have that $t_c\leq t_\gamma$, so $y(c(t_c))
=\int_0^{t_c}\sin(\alpha_c(t))dt=
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha_c(0)}\min\{t;\alpha_c(t)>\alpha\}d\alpha
\leq
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha_\gamma(0)}\min\{t;\alpha_\gamma(t)>\alpha\}d\alpha$
$=\int_0^{t_\gamma}\sin(\alpha_\gamma(t))dt=y(c(t_\gamma))$, where the non trivial equalities come from Fubini (we calculate the area under the graph of the function horizontally instead of vertically). So finally, we have $b=y(c(t_c))+(b-y(c(t_c)))\leq y(\gamma(t_\gamma))+(b-y(\gamma(t_\gamma)))=b$, with equality iff $\alpha_c(t)=\alpha_\gamma(t)$ for all $t$, so $c=\gamma$. $\square$

Now back to the question: suppose that we have a convex curve $\gamma$ passing through all the points of $X$ (the points of $X$ are the vertices of a polygon $\mathcal{P}$, and maybe some additional points in edges of $\mathcal{P}$). Let $x,y$ be points of $X$ that appear consecutively in $\gamma$, with $\gamma(a)=x$, $\gamma(b)=y$ for some $a,b$. We can find some curve $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ going from $x$ to $y$, with $f'(a)=\gamma'(a)$, $f'(b)=\gamma'(b)$ and such that $f$ has less curvature that $\gamma$ in [a,b].

(!!) We can only apply the claim when the sum of the two angles $\gamma$ forms with each side is $<\pi$ (indeed, in the claim the angle  $\alpha(t)$ has a total variation $<\pi$). However if the sum of the angles in the claim was $\pi$, we can extend the curve by segments without increasing the curvature, and if it is $>\pi$, we can achieve arbitrarily low curvature using the same trick. From now on we will assume that these sums of angles are $<\pi$. This is always true for polygons in which the sum of any two consecutive exterior angles is $<\pi$ (this is not a very restrictive condition, as all exterior angles add up to $2\pi$), but it may not work with triangles for example.

We can summarize this in the following result:

For any convex convex curve $\gamma$ passing through the points of $X$, there is another convex curve $f$ passing through the points of $X$ such that:

- $f'(x)=\gamma'(x)\;\forall x\in X$.
- The arc of $f$ between any two consecutive points $x,y\in X$ is formed by a segment and/or an arc of circumference.
- $f$ has less maximal curvature than $\gamma$.

In fact the curve $f$ is uniquely determined by the values of $\gamma'(x)$ for each $x$ in $X$. So what we have to do is look for the values of $\gamma'(x)$ for each $x$ in $X$ which make the maximal curvature of $f$ be minimal.

We can also use this to prove that the curve with min-max curvature exists: first of all, let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of edges of $\mathcal{P}$, and let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ be the subset of edges of $\mathcal{P}$ contained in $\gamma$; then $\mathcal{A}$ can only take finitely many values, and for each one we can prove that there is a curve of min-max curvature using a compactness argument (curvature depends continuously on the values $f'(x)$ for $x\in X$, except when $f'(x)$ is parallel to a segment of $\mathcal{P}$ containing $x$, and when $f'(x)$ approaches that segment the curvature gets large so we don't care).

So to minimize the maximal curvature you can, for each value of $\mathcal{A}$, write the maximal curvature of $f$ in terms of the angles $f'(x)$ forms with the sides of $\mathcal{P}$, and then the problem essentially becomes minimizing some functions with domain $[0,1]^n$. Probably dividing in cases depending on $\mathcal{A}$ of edges contained in $\gamma$ will be unavoidable, but I'm sure there is some way to make this more efficient than just checking all the subsets $\mathcal{A}$.

Edit: I decided to add the explicit expression of the radius of curvature.

Suppose that $l$ is a side of $\mathcal{P}$ with length $x$ and the convex curve $c$ formed by segments and arcs of circumference is like in the figure below, forming angles $\alpha\geq\beta$ (with $\alpha+\beta<\pi$) with the side $l$.

[image]

Then it's not difficult to check that the radius of curvature of the circumference arc is $x\frac{\sin(\beta)(1+\cos(\alpha+\beta))}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)^2}$. Note that for fixed $\alpha+\beta$, the minimum curvature is achieved for $\alpha=\beta$, and in the case $\alpha=\beta\geq0$, the curvature increases with $\alpha$.

**Claim:** If the points of $X$ are in a circumference and the condition in (!!) is satisfied, then $c$ achieves min-max curvature.

$\textit{Proof:}$ Let $\gamma$ be a $C^1$ convex curve containing all points of $X$ which minimizes maximal curvature. For each side $l$ let $\alpha_l=\beta_l$ be the angles that $c$ forms with $l$, and let $\alpha_l'\geq\beta_l'$ be the angles that $\gamma$ forms with $l$. Then $\sum_l\alpha_l+\beta_l=2\pi=\sum_l\alpha_l'+\beta_l'$. But for each $l$ we have $\alpha_l+\beta_l\geq\alpha_l'+\beta_l'$, because $\gamma$ minimizes curvature, so $\alpha_l+\beta_l=\alpha_l'+\beta_l'$ for all $l$. Again, as $\gamma$ minimizes curvature, we need to have $\alpha_l'=\beta_l'$ for all $l$, so $\gamma=c$ as we wanted. $\square$

Comment: The expression for the radius of curvature can be nicer using $$\cot(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2)=\frac{1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$ (and by naming the length with a letter that doesn’t look like a derivative).

Answer (score 9):

(This answer was posted before the convexity condition on the curve $\gamma$ was added to the question)

Suppose you have any finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and rotate $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that they have pairwise distinct $y$-coordinates. Then we can create curves with arbitrarily low curvature passing through all the points. Here is an idea of what they would look like:

[image]

You can make the curves from the sides arbitrarily large, thus making their curvatures arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thank you ! I see the point. I should simply add the constraint that $\gamma$ is convex. I guess I have to make another post. On the other hand, I think such convex curve passing through a set of points $X$ should have already be studied, but it seems there are not reference about it anyway.

Comment: Yes, that constraint would make the problem more interesting :) you can just add it to the question, I won't be offended or anything

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot! :)

Comment: SaúlRM, in your opinion should I simplify the whole text by talking only about curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I think that would be a good problem to begin, and it is much easier to state. I thought a bit about that case but I didn't find anything special

Answer (score 4):

Here is one limit on the curvature needed. It is not optimal, but it is explicit, and probably a good starting point for numerical or theoretical optimization.

**Proposition:** Consider the convex hull of the vertices as a polygon; then there is a path through the vertices with curvature of at most
$$\max_i \frac{1+\cos(t_i+u_i)}{s_i\cos(\max(t_i,u_i))}$$
where $s_i$ is the length of the side and $t_i$, $u_i$ are half the angles at its vertices.

The path will go through each vertex in a direction perpendicular to the angle bisector at that vertex.

**Proof:** For consecutive vertices $V,W$, take their angle bisectors, and let the perpendiculars to those bisectors intersect at $S$.

[image: diagram]

Let triangle $SVW$ have side lengths $s,v,w$ and assume wlog that $v\le w$. Let $V’$ be the point on $SV$ with $VV’=w-v$.

Then our path will go through the line segment $VV’$, and a circular arc through $V’$ and $W$ which is tangent to $SV$ and $SW$. Since this section of path is perpendicular to the angular bisector at each vertex, it will have the same direction at each vertex as the path from the other side, and our final construction can combine these path sections for all sides.

If $t$ and $u$ are the angles between the convex hull and the respective angle bisectors at $V$ and $W$, then the angle at $S$ is $t+u$. So the radius of the circle arc is $v\tan(\frac{t+u}2)$ and by the law of sines this is
$$\frac{s \cos t}{\sin(t+u)}\ \tan(\frac{t+u}2)$$ We can rewrite $t$ as $\max(t,u)$ because $v\le w$, and rewrite $\tan(\frac{t+u}2)/\sin(t+u)$ as $1/(1+\cos(t+u))$. Then inverting the rewritten radius gives the original expression in the formula for the curvature. $\square$

**Example:**

[[image: diagram from WolframAlpha]]

Let the vertices be $(\pm2,\pm1)$ and $(\pm3,0)$. Then each side length is $\sqrt{2}$ or $4$, and each vertex half-angle is $\pi/4$ or $3\pi/8$. So the curvature is
$$\max(\frac{1+\cos(\frac{5\pi}8)}{\sqrt{2}\cos(\frac{3\pi}8)},
\frac{1+\cos(\frac{3\pi}4)}{4\cos(\frac{3\pi}8)})
$$
which gives $\sim1.14$.

The apparent minimum possible maximum curvature for this example is $1$, achieved by the union of two vertical semicircles and two horizontal lines.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Interesting observations!

Comment: Thanks! Now it is less detailed and better.

Comment: @BeniBogosel, I allow discontinuities in the curvature but not in the tangent. This seems reasonable to me, and probably any limit of smooth approximately-optimal curves would be of this form.

Comment: @MattF. another way to interpret it as defining "maximum curvature" as the minimum Lipschitz constant of the function $t\mapsto \gamma'(t)$